# how to draw a perimeter of a given length?

Tags: geometry

Given a grid where the tick length is one unit, such as the one below,
draw a perimeter of 17 unit.

I'm interested in the answer and also in a general approach to solve this kind of problem.

One general approach I tried is to draw a square of a smaller perimeter, say
$$
 3+3+3+3 = 12, \text{or} \\
 4+4+4+4 = 16.
$$
And then figure out a way to modify the smaller square to get the desired perimeter. I can only modify the side of such a square by adding two units, say
$$
 [1+(1+1+1)+1=5]+3+3+3=14,
$$
that is by creating a small dent on a side.
But then, I can only add multiple of 2 units, and not an odd numbers.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean a figure with perimeter $17$? If do, this is not possible. To see why, note that if you walk around such a figure, you have to make the same number of steps up and down and the same number of steps left and right.

Comment: Are triangles allowed?

Comment: @Wojowu I see, that's why it can't be done.

Comment: @HEKTO Let's say yes, because Wojowu showed it's not possible otherwise.

Comment: @nicolas I don't think that allowing triangles would make odd perimeters possible, either. Casually speaking, reason is that (a) irrational square roots of integers are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, so each hypotenuse would need to be an integer itself, and (b) pythagorean triangles have even perimeter.